# Can a player get the second place points with no Maki Rolls in Sushi Go?

Tags: sushi-go

In a two player game of Sushi Go!, if only one player has Maki Rolls they would get the 6 points since they have the most of that type of card. Does the second player get the 3 points since they technically have the second most amount, or do they have to have at least one Maki Roll card to be able to get the 3 points?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to have at least one Maki Roll to score. This clarification is missing from the Gamewright English rules, but some other versions (including [this German one](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/108730/sushi-go-german-rules-zoch-version)) include it.